# How to recognize the click on a spinner button in an input with type number?

Tags: jquery

I'm trying with this code:

```
$("input[type=number]::-webkit-inner-spin-button").click( function() {
    setTimeout(function(){
       $(this).attr('disabled', true); 
    }, 3000);
});
```

But without success. I need to set a delay between the clicks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't select pseudo elements like `::-webkit-inner-spin-button` with JavaScript or jQuery because they aren't part of the DOM. But you could instead listen on the `change` event of the input.

Furthermore `$(this)` doesn't work in the inner function of `setTimeout()`. Therefor you have to store it in a variable (that is in the scope of that function).

And last: If you want to set a delay between the clicks you have to change the `disabled` attribute immediately. The function in the `setTimeout` is executed after the delay and should be used to set `disabled` to `false`, so that you can click again on the spin buttons.

**Working example:**

```js
$('input[type=number]').on('change', function() {
  let input = $(this);
  input.attr('disabled', true);
  setTimeout(function() {
    input.attr('disabled', false);
  }, 3000);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<label for="quantity">Quantity (between 1 and 5):</label>
<input type="number" id="quantity" name="quantity" min="1" max="5">
```